# Variable arguments with EXP4J? How?

Tags: java, android, parsing

Is it even possible? Their Git page suggests so. Currently it's only possible to declare vararg'd functions in a simple context, but for my purpose I need something like:

`func(1,2,3,4,5)+func(1,2)+func(1,2,3)`

In this scenario, simply declaring a local function with a variable number of arguments won't work as the expression evaluator can have only one definition.

I also want to avoid the silly solution of creating a function for every `n` arguments...

Answer (score 1):

something like that? 
also it would have to send the formula to func

```
String formula=  "a * sin(b) - 35 / (c - 2)"; //3 var
String formula2= "a * sin(b) - d / (c - 2)";  //4 var

String[] ve = new String[3];
ve[0] = "a";
ve[1] = "b";
ve[2] = "c";

Map<String, Double> vars = new HashMap<>(); 

vars.put("a", 1.5);
vars.put("b", 2.0);
vars.put("c", 3.2);

//----------------------Here func(string ....

Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder(formula)
.variables(ve)
.build()
.setVariables(vars);

double result = e.evaluate();
```

Comment: The question is about functions with a variable amount of arguments, not variables themselves.